# Are PhoneGap native API usable right from the mobile browser?

Tags: javascript, mobile, cordova

I'm setting up a website that features audio record right from the browser.
For the desktop version, I'll be using WebRTC (even if it's in its early days).
For the mobile version, I plan to use PhoneGap to access microphone.

Do I have to make a PhoneGap app (built & "native") and embed my website in an InAppBrowser or can I access microphone with the PhoneGap.js library right from the whatever-mobile browser ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Take a look at Capture API. http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.6.1/cordova_media_capture_capture.md.html#Capture

Comment: Yes to what part ? :)
I did take a look, because it's especially this part that interests me. But my question was more in the context use of this Capture API. Is it in-app only (meaning, built and run from the phone menu like any regular app) or does it work in the mobile browser by just refering to PhoneGap.js library ?

Comment: All phonegap libraries need to be built into an app as they are just bridges to native code. I think the answer above is stating that some of the PhoneGap APIs use native HTML5 functionality that you could build yourself outside of phonegap.

Comment: I tried to access a page on an InAppBrowser instance, with this script inside :

`if(navigator.notification) alert('notifications are OK.');
  else alert('notifications are not OK.');`

The alert returns "not OK" (the Notification API is in my `config.xml`). Maybe you will see what I'm trying to do. I would like to access the PhoneGap API from my already-made web app (with any solution). I don't know if I made myself clear enough... I just don't want to rewrite the whole web app. There must be a solution, right ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a regular web application that would work on mobile devices I do not think PhoneGap is the solution here.

If I understand you correctly you want to be able to record audio from the device's microphone. There are several HTML5 libraries that you could use but I haven't found one that supports Android.

One example is the [Web Audio API](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webaudio/intro/) which at least supports [iOS >7](http://caniuse.com/#search=web%20audio%20api).

Here's an article on [Capturing audio](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/) in HTML5.

However you could use PhoneGap to "frame" your web application that would be installable onto mobile devices and then use the [PhoneGap Media API](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media/blob/master/doc/index.md) which seems widely supported across platforms. But as far as I'm concerned it is not possible to use the PhoneGap APi's from your regular web application.

Comment: Thanks. But I think actual recording function of the Web Audio API is brought by getUserMedia(), which is [not yet available](http://caniuse.com/#feat=stream) on iOS (nor Android & Safari).